# Book about corporations creating genetic "blanks" who can change their DNA

Tags: story-identification, novel, hard-sci-fi, espionage

I've been searching for this novel since the '90s and been unable to remember the title or author. I pray someone here can help me.

The story is set in the future where corporations run everything. Corporate sabotage has become so prevalent that security measures have reached the point where DNA identification is required for access. To get around this corporations have found a way to genetically create human blanks. These are people with no real identity of their own who when given a disc with another persons genetic pattern they can become that person by inserting the disc into a drive on I believe their stomachs. The story follows one of these genetic "blanks" through a drive to freedom and a rebellion of the "blanks" against their corporate owners. The resistance was lead by a group of gladiator blanks who were given discs with modified dna so they could have animal characteristics as well. If i remember correctly one was a centaur however instead of his lower body being a horse it was a scorpion.

If anyone can tell me either the author or name of this book, I would be forever grateful. It would be an end to a 20 year search.

Comment: Is "blanks" the term used in the book? You mention gladiators that change partly into animals. Would you say this is a classical cyberpunk setting or is it more like the scifi books that were inspired by the Animorphs?

Comment: if i remember correctly blanks was a term used. However this is set far in the future versus animorphs which was set present day. Also the blanks lack any genitalia in their original state though they have their own personalities and identities

Comment: Do you recall any names from the story? Is the location stated? You read it in the late 90's but do you have any inkling how old the book could be? Was it recently published or could it be from the 80's? Have you got a feeling if it's a young adult (YA)  book? Did you find it in a specific library?

Comment: The "blanks" can drastically alter their body shape from  a mere DNA change. Is that "hard sci-fi"?

Comment: Its not a young adult book. Its a full length novel involving adult themes. Was found in a public library in ontario. I dont remember the characters names. Though the main character was male. It was written After CD technology became available I believe. Also what is the definiton of hard sci to?

Comment: It looks like it was solved on [sffchronicles.com](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/579329/) Masque by F. Paul Wilson and Matthew Costello